# Zend frame work compare two files

Tags: zend-framework

I want compare two text files using zend_frame work mvc pattern model.
How can i do that, it is possible perform this task?

If yes means please provide me some idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure Zend will do this job.

Let's take a look to [Horde_Text_Diff](http://pear.horde.org/) PEAR package.